# Is there a bitcoin market for CPU time / memory space / disk space?

Tags: cpu, marketplace, storage-footprint

Bitcoin mining pools are like lending / borrowing cpu time, but it's only for hashing.
Is there something more general; a market where you can lend and borrow cpu time, disk space and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not exactly what you are asking for but [CoinLab](http://coinlab.com/) have a mining pool that intends to use the computing power of their members for jobs other than hashing.

From the Bitcoin talk [forum topic](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=99643.msg1089915#msg1089915):

> We’ve identified a number of opportunities to monetize our growing GPU cluster at a higher rate than Bitcoin mining, particularly for NVIDIA cards:  Protein Folding, Computational Finance, and Big Data Analysis, just to name a few.